# Will Google index a site which forces HTTPS or SSL?

Tags: seo, https, google-index

We are having problems getting Google to index our site. We decided it was easiest to just use https for the entire site.

Do we need to change it so that the anonymous, "public", areas of the site are not encrypted for them to be indexed?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, SEO questions are related to web development and programming (stackoverflow) and not server setup/administration (serverfault).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, they'll index https just fine.  Remember that https is a transport protocol to ensure that folks in the middle of the wire can't eavesdrop (. . . as easily . . . ) or muck w /the traffic.

They will not index password protected portions, of course.

Answer (score 9):

They do.  Here's another references: http://www.google.com/search?q=mdc+javascript  First result is an https address

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they will.

Example search:
`http://www.google.com/search?q=%22SSL+Certificates+-+Secure+Your+Data+%26+Transactions%22+site%3Agodaddy.com`

You should see a result indicating the URL is "`https://www.godaddy.com/gdshop/ssl/ssl.asp`".